# Azure Pipeline : ASP.NET and .NET Core applications under one build pipeline

Tags: asp.net, azure-pipelines

**Background:**

I have several ASP.NET projects under one solution file. I have a build pipeline for ASP.NET projects and building it with .sln.
Now, we have added a new project to the same .sln which is in .NET CORE.

**Problem statement:**

In my build pipeline, when I try to build the whole solution, it throws an exception to the newly added project. (.NET CORE)

> "The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace
> 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I believe this is due to framework versions.

**Question**:

Is it possible to have both projects under one build pipeline, if yes, how can I achieve it? if not, what would be the ideal solution?

Additional information: From the visual studio, everything is building and working fine, but I build the project pipeline it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by updating the NuGet package version for the pipeline. Same as the application version.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a reference to `System.Data.Entity` to test if the exception is thrown again.

Or you could refer to this document for more details about [Organize your project to support both .NET Framework and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure)

================================================================

**updated on 11/30**

This error message indicates the build process can't find the assemblies coming from the restored nuget packages. So you should check the log of the restore task in build-pipeline to make sure the packages are restored successfully.

Make sure you have use `nuget tool install` and `nuget restore` tasks before your build task like this, if your build include private feed, please add the `nuget authenticate task` to restore the project correctly. (Avoid using dotnet related tasks cause your project targets .net framework, and dotnet task could not recognize .sln projects)

[image]

Comment: Additional information: From the visual studio, everything is building and working fine, but i build the project pipeline it's throwing this error.

Comment: @Schatak could you share your pipeline configuration for further investigation?

Comment: NuGet restore is working fine, but the Build step is failing. Also, am not using nuget authentication task for now.

Comment: Hi @Schatak what's the assembly are you using? as the azure devops hosted agent is gradually [migrating to .net6.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-of-net-agent-for-azure-pipelines/), I suppose you need to keep the compatibility with this target framework. By the way, have you tested with [self hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: I was able to resolve this by updating the NuGet package version, not sure what else I did but it got fixed, thanks mate.

Comment: @Schatak great to hear this, you could post your own answer and [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), or if my answers helped, you could consider to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

*Initially build the code from visual studio to avoid errors while building in the azure pipeline*.

*Used different projects in azure pipeline*
[image]
*Create a repository using Visual Studio or Azure Devops.*
[image]

*Fill the necessary fields while creating a repository*
[image]

*Then it enters into a Git Credential Manager screen and have to choose the account from which you want to create and proceed further.*

[image]
*Create branches if required.*
[image]
*Using Visual Studio, we can sync and push the changes made from the specific branch*
[image]

[image]
[image]
*Create a pipeline with azure subscription and build the code.*

*Refer this* [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure) *for more info.*

Comment: thanks for the help, but that's not what my question is.